# How to force specific Chrome behavior through a shorcut

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, shortcuts

I tried making a shortcut to Chrome and making it launch Minimized and go to a specific webpage. If I don't have Chrome already open, this shortcut works exactly as intended. If I **do** have Chrome already open, it just opens in a new tab in the existing window.

Additionally, if I use this shortcut then use my "regular" Chrome shortcut (that doesn't specify a website or anything), it opens future Chrome windows in a non-maximized window which is also really annoying.

Is this possible?

Comment: That seems to be more just a general list of command line switches rather than the specific nuances of different Chrome instances interacting funny. Read through them all and don't think I saw anything that'd make them interact independently

Comment: The limitation of "through a shortcut" restricts you to command line switches.  Provided you don't want to build your own wrapper...

Comment: You are probably best off looking into writing a couple of AutoIt or AutoHotkey scripts to automate this process, what you are after is nontrivial and almost certainly impossible via a command line or batch file.